# How can I pass the data from RecyclerView (ProductActivity) to DetailActivity?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-intent, android-recyclerview

In this project, I have to make a RecyclerView that will fetch the Firebase data. When someone clicks on any particular item in the RecyclerView, I want to open DetailActivity with the same data fetched from the Firebase.
I know this is easy and can be done using intent.putExtra but I'm new here in Kotlin.
Help me with the solution, please.

Below I'm attaching my code of `ProductActivity.kt`.

```
class ProductActivity() : AppCompatActivity(), ProductAdapter.OnItemClickListener
{
private var adapter: ProductAdapter? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_product)

    val query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("products")
    val options = FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Product>().setQuery(query, 
    Product::class.java).build()
    adapter = ProductAdapter(options, this)
    val rView : RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rView)
    rView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    rView.adapter = adapter
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    adapter?.startListening()
}

override fun onItemClick(position: Int) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Item $position clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    val intent = Intent(this, DetailActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
 }
}
```

The code of `ProductAdapter.kt`

```
class ProductAdapter(options: FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Product>, private val listener: OnItemClickListener)
: FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Product, ProductAdapter.MyViewHolder>(options) {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    return MyViewHolder(inflater, parent)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int, model: Product) {

    val storRef: StorageReference =
        FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(model.photo)
    Glide.with(holder.imgPhoto.context).load(storRef).into(holder.imgPhoto)
    holder.txtName.text = model.name
    holder.txtPrice.text = model.price
    holder.txtDescription.text = model.description
}

inner class MyViewHolder(inflater: LayoutInflater, parent: ViewGroup) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false)), View.OnClickListener {
    val txtName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.productName)
    val txtPrice: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.productPrice)
    val txtDescription: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.productDescription)
    val imgPhoto: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.productImage)

    init {
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
        val position: Int = adapterPosition
        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
            listener.onItemClick(position)
        }
    }
}

interface OnItemClickListener {
    fun onItemClick(position: Int)
  }
}
```

The activity in which I want to pass data `DetailActivity.kt`

```
class DetailActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail)

  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Besides that, the code in this [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FireApp) will definitely help, pass data to another activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you want to send name, address, and phone number to detail your activity,
in Java you would do like this inside the itemclick Listener

//Get the values from the model class

```
  intent.putExtra("name", model.get(position).getName);
    intent.putExtra("address", model.get(position).getAddress);
    intent.putExtra("phone", model.get(position).getPhone);
```

then on the DetailsActivity get the intent and set the values in their respective views.

Comment: `p` in `intent.PutExtra()` is lowecase.

Answer (score -2):

SendingActivity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SendingActivity.this, RecievingActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("keyName", value);  // pass your values and retrieve them in the other Activity using keyName
startActivity(intent);
```

RecievingActivity

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if(extras != null)
    String data = extras.getString("keyName"); // retrieve the data using keyName
```

in your project
"SendingActivity" must be replaced by "ProductActivity" and
"ReceivingActivity" must be replaced by "DetailActivity".

Comment: I have used Serializable, Parceable, and MutableList .. but none of them worked for me. As I said earlier that I'm new to this language and can't figure out the solution on my own. I have made this app work this much by learning different things from the internet and now I need help in this case.

Comment: Please read the question and the code before posting an answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).